# Populating attributes of smaller polygons using bigger polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, fields-attributes, census

I have polygons TAZs (Travel Analysis Zones) that do not have any county information in them. I want to populate these TAZs with COUNTYFIPS that would have county codes in which these polygons are present using County shapefiles.

I have tried intersection but it is changing the boundary of the TAZs.

How can I approach this?

Comment: try a spatial join https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked for 3000 values out of 3528